# Discord.js Role.id.client is undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have the following issue: I'm using Role.id.client to check if the user has the following role. It does throw the error on the bottom, but the term should be correct.
Can somebody help me?

```
client.on("voiceStateUpdate", (oldState, newState) => {

    if(newState.channelId === `937722527894089806` && Role.id.client ==! `938113190041124885`) {
```

The error code:

```
[nodemon] starting `node src/index.js`
Ready! Logged in as Rainbow Six | DE Test Bot#0280!
C:\Users\emre2\Desktop\Coding\Visualstudiodateien\src\index.js:56
    if(Role.id.client ==! `938113190041124885`) {    //Warten
           ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'client')
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\emre2\Desktop\Coding\Visualstudiodateien\src\index.js:56:16)
    at Client.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at VoiceStateUpdate.handle (C:\Users\emre2\Desktop\Coding\Visualstudiodateien\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\VoiceStateUpdate.js:38:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as VOICE_STATE_UPDATE] (C:\Users\emre2\Desktop\Coding\Visualstudiodateien\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\VOICE_STATE_UPDATE.js:4:35)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\emre2\Desktop\Coding\Visualstudiodateien\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:351:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\emre2\Desktop\Coding\Visualstudiodateien\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\emre2\Desktop\Coding\Visualstudiodateien\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\emre2\Desktop\Coding\Visualstudiodateien\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:199:18)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\emre2\Desktop\Coding\Visualstudiodateien\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:1098:20)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Can you show us the whole code of the file? Seems like there's something wrong with your `client` variable

Comment: What is `Role` supposed to be? IDs don't have clients... they are strings